# Border 0px broken line

Tags: html, css, border

EDIT: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rezv2/)

I'm trying to have a top and left border with rounded edges, yet my code gives me a broken line on the bottom and right sides, as shown in the picture below. Setting `border-right-width` or `border-bottom-width` to 0px has no effect. At present I am only testing this on Chrome.

CSS as follows:

```
border-top:10px solid #CC99CC;
border-left:5px solid #CC99CC;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
```

[image]

Comment: can u post html or better a jsfiddle?

Comment: As we can see there are two `link buttons` inside, so first try removing them and see if you get proper `border` if you get it proper then there must be problem of overlapping of `div`.

Comment: The buttons inside are `div`s with rounded corners, and `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply your border styles to the #wrapper instead:

```
body { 
    background-color: #000;
}

#wrapper {
    border-top:10px solid #CC99CC;
    border-left:5px solid #CC99CC;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rezv2/2/